# Expected chunk of type 0x180, read 0x100

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, android-ksoap2, dot42

I am trying to use the ksaop2-android library with Dot42 and after getting to a point where I thought I could test, I get the above error after a successful build.  I am starting in debug mode.  I have never seen this kind of error before and have no idea where to even start correcting it.  I have successfully run the default app template for Dot42 after the latest update. I am using Visual Studio 2012.  I have enabled the INTERNET permission in the manifest file. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Os;
using Android.Widget;
using Dot42;
using Dot42.Manifest;
using Org.Ksoap2.Serialization;
using Org.Ksoap2.Transport;


[assembly: Application("dot42Application7")]

namespace dot42Application7
{

    [Activity]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
    private string NAMESPACE = "http://reps.catalystinnovations.net/";
    private string URL = "http://reps.catalystpromotions.net/T-ShirtPricing.asmx";

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstance);
        SetContentView(R.Layouts.MainLayout);
        TryWebService();
    }

    public void TryWebService()
    {
        string METHOD_NAME = "GetTShirtPricingString";
        string SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo password = new PropertyInfo();
        password.SetName("password");
        password.SetValue("password");
        password.SetType(typeof(string));

        PropertyInfo numColors = new PropertyInfo();
        numColors.SetName("color");
        numColors.SetValue("White");
        // numColors.setValue("White");
        numColors.SetType(typeof(string));

        PropertyInfo numShirts = new PropertyInfo();
        numShirts.SetName("weight");
        double w = 5.4d;
        numShirts.SetValue(w.ToString());
        // numShirts.setValue("5.4");
        numShirts.SetType(typeof(string));

        request.AddProperty(password);
        request.AddProperty(numColors);
        request.AddProperty(numShirts);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(Org.Ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.DotNet = true;
        envelope.SetOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.ImplicitTypes = true;

        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try
        {
            transport.Call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.GetResponse();
            string result = response.ToString();
            int i = 0;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try equivalent code in Java/Eclipse to rule out a problem unrelated to the dot42 compiler?

Comment: Not this specific code, but I have gotten this library to work many time in eclipse and Java

Comment: I just tried this code in SharpDevelop and got more inforamtion:

Comment: Unhandled WPF exception
Exception thrown:
System.IO.IOException: Expected chunk of type 0x180, read 0x100.
   at w.njs..ctor(nqv , nqo )
   at w.nqf..ctor(nqv )
   at w.nqr..ctor(nqv )
   at w.njy.ti()
   at Dot42.SharpDevelop.Dot42ProjectBehavior.Start(Boolean withDebugging)
   at ICSharpCode.SharpDevelop.Project.ProjectBehavior.Start(Boolean withDebugging)
   at ICSharpCode.SharpDevelop.Project.ProjectBehavior.Start(Boolean withDebugging)
   at ICSharpCode.SharpDevelop.Project.AbstractProject.Start(Boolean withDebugging)

Comment: at ICSharpCode.SharpDevelop.Project.Commands.Execute.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Run>b__0(Object param0, EventArgs param1)
   at ICSharpCode.SharpDevelop.Project.Commands.AbstractBuildMenuCommand.OnBuildComplete(EventArgs e)
   at ICSharpCode.SharpDevelop.Project.Commands.AbstractBuildMenuCommand.CallbackMethod(BuildResults results)
   at ICSharpCode.SharpDevelop.Project.BuildEngine.<ReportDone>b__3()
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at

Comment: MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)  Is the message I get, I hope this is helpful.  I still have no idea what is going on